# Qt Disable QTextEdit without disabling scroll bar

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtextedit

In qt how do you disable a QTextEdit without disabling the scroll bar? Its for previewing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the QTextEdit as read only:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#readOnly-prop

If you want it to "look disabled", you can also set the foreground and background roles to the disabled colors.